# Jekyll Blog Contact Page Permalink not Working

Tags: url, jekyll, permalinks, github-pages, base-url

I have my Jekyll blog set up here: [My blog](http://edsonmendieta.com/blog/)

I forked this blog theme from https://github.com/johnotander/pixyll

and created a github pages for it using the Master branch and changed the name of the repository to '**blog**'.

My github.io repo is used for my personal site **and** uses the CNAME: edsonmendieta.com

So, my blog is at edsonmendieta.com/blog.

In my _config.yml: https://github.com/edsonmendieta/blog/blob/master/_config.yml

I've set the url to: 'http://edsonmendieta.com/blog/'

My blog theme, has a contact page which had '**permalink**' set to /contact/,
but after clicking it, the url path was edsonmendieta.com/contact, and I got a github 404.

I changed the permalink to blog/contact/ and now I still get a 404 but one that's themed by my blog theme.

I don't know why I'm getting a 404.

The 'baseurl' in my config.yml file is empty ("").

Should I change the '**baseurl**' and '**url**' in the **_config.yml** file?

Should I change the '**permalink**' in the **contact** file?

Help is GREATLY appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In config, set :

```
url: http://edsonmendieta.com
baseurl: /blog
```

And it's supposed to work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the permalink on the contact page and it should work. You can even remove it, jekyll will take care of it for you.

Comment: Removing it changed the path to edsonmendieta.com/contact/ which resulted in a github404. I don't know what I should change It to....

Comment: @Edson take a look at: (https://byparker.com/blog/2014/clearing-up-confusion-around-baseurl/)

Comment: I've actually read that, and did use /blog as the base url, but was still getting issues.